# Node backpack exclude file from bundling

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have the simplest backpack config like this:

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, options, webpack) => {
      config.entry.main = [
        './app.js'
      ]
      return config;
    }
}
```

But inside my app I have

```
const myConfig = require('./config/someConfiguration.json');
```

This file `./config/someConfiguration.json` should not be bundled so that it can be modified/configured. 
I tried to do it like that:

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, options, webpack) => {
      config.entry.main = [
        './app.js'
      ];
      config.externals = [
        './config/someConfiguration.json'
      ];
      return config;
    }
}
```

But then I had 2 issues. One small one was that now I have to include the file like that `'../config/someConfiguration.json'` since it is required from the `./build/main.js` bundled script. The other issue was that MySQL module started to throw exception out of nowhere:

```
    this.handshake = Packets.Handshake.fromPacket(helloPacket);
                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromPacket' of undefined...
```

Which I think means that I am not excluding the file from bundling as it should be. What's the proper way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Externals are only for modules/librairies, do not use them for single files. 
Use loaders instead like this :

```
config.module.loaders = [
    {
         test: /\.json$/,
         loader: 'json-loader'
    }
];
```

You have to install the `json-loader` package therefore.